# Android L ripple effect not displayed

Tags: android

I've created a `RecyclerView` and set up an `onItemClickListener` to show an `Activity`, an `AlertDialog` or a `Fragment`.  When I click to display the Activity or the Alert, it shows the ripple effect, but when I click on to display a Fragment, it doesn't.  How can I make the ripple effect show when clicking on the Fragment list item?

Here's a [link](https://github.com/rtteal/RippleIssue) to my source if you're interested.

[image]

Comment: Post the relevant part of your source code here, don't just link to it. You can leave the link as a reference for those who want to play around with your complete source, but the question itself should contain all the information necessary to answer the question. Also links tend to break so as soon as that link is not valid anymore your question essentially becomes useless. So please edit your question and add the relevant parts of your source code. You can also read [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing a fragment is an instantaneous action, displaying an alert is delayed. The ripple animation happens while the alert is being displayed with the default fade-in animation as they're both playing at the same time; but not when changing fragments because there's no time for it.

You can try delaying replacing your fragment by means of an empty animation or a Timer thread.

Another option is adding an animation to the fragment transaction in a way that it allows for the ripple animation to finish.

Comment: And this is not part of the answer, but in general I would ignore ripple effects for transition actions as they're not backwards compatible and you don't get access to its animation listener to do stuff afterwards.